# I'm trying to restrict access to my Azure webapp to a specific User group

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

My On-prem AD is in sync with Azure AD and Im trying to give access to my Azure hosted website (Webapp) to a specific set of user(AD groups) via seamless login

I alredy tried setting different option avail in App registration but none of them worked as expected

Comment: Refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-restrict-your-app-to-a-set-of-users).

Comment: @JoeyCai Thanks a ton, it worked like a charm. I tried the same yesterday but when trying to add user it was only showing the users(not groups) and was stuck up there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the App which registered in your Azure AD, click `Managed application in local directory`> `Properties`>  `User assignment required` to **Yes**.

When this option is set to Yes, **users must first be assigned to this application before they can access it.** Then assign users and groups to the app.

[image]

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-restrict-your-app-to-a-set-of-users).